# javascript error when exiting for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, onchange

I created a jquery utility, that when you select a state from a drop down, it automatically shows the states. To make the user experience better, I added some logic to divide the stores across three columns. This is working correctly in every browser except IE.

I am not sure that the error displayed in the console is the same error that is causing the `.change()` event to not trigger in IE, but I thought I would mention it. The console error that I am getting is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'store_url' of undefined

Here is the code:

```
else if (store_remainder === 0) {
   for(var i = 0; i < check; i++) {
      store_col_1.append("<li class='current_store'><a href='" +   data[i].store_url + "'>" + data[i].store_name + "</a></li>");
   }
   for(var i = check; i < (check * 2); i++) {
      store_col_2.append("<li class='current_store'><a href='" + data[i].store_url + "'>" + data[i].store_name + "</a></li>");
   }
   for(var i = (check * 2); i <= data.length; i++) {
      store_col_3.append("<li class='current_store'><a href='" + data[i].store_url + "'>" + data[i].store_name + "</a></li>");
   }    
}
```

The error comes up only in the final "for" block, which makes me believe that it tries to run the last iteration but doesn't get a value and comes back as null. If this is the case, how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for this that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
for(var i = (check * 2); i <= data.length; i++) {
```

must be:

```
for(var i = (check * 2); i < data.length; i++) {
       //without '=' -------^
```

as `somearray[somearray.length]` is **always** `undefined`.

Comment: The reason being, of cource, that array indices are 0 based, so the highest index is `length - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

in `for(var i = (check * 2); i<= data.length; i++)`

your error exists in the `<=`.  Change that to a `<`

Answer (score 0):

On your last loop, you should use :

```
for(var i = (check * 2); i < data.length; i++)
```

as data[data.length] is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your last for go to **i < data.length** as opposed to **i <= data.length**?